# CSS word vertical scale

Tags: html, css, scale, cpu-word

I want to place the word vertical-align:middle. (Always in the middle of div when scaling the browser). I have tried a lot of methods but fail to keep it in the middle when scale. How can I do that?

```
<div class="word">
    <h1>Hello!!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: vertical align works with "display:table-cell". you need to give this css display property to the div above

Comment: but if i want to horizontal-align:right and vertical-align:middle. How can i make it work.

Comment: you can try use flex. you have answer in this post. or you can add to my answer "text-align-right" property to this div. try this - https://fiddle.jshell.net/5o7vqngs/1/

Comment: Can it be scale text? because i have the scale image beside

Comment: @Kindess some of your comments below are asking about an image - there is no image in your question - and about fitting text. We can't format a correct answer if we don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this basic approach:

```css
    .word {
        height: 90px;
        background: #000;
        color: #FFF;
        line-height: 90px;
    }
    h1{
      font-size:5.9vw;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="word">
     <h1>Hello!!</h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: the OP is asking for it to be in the center when the browser scales - this is fixed.

Comment: if i want to make it horizontal-align on the right hand side how can i do it. Can it be scale text?  because i have the scale image beside

Comment: just in h1 tag you have to add one more style text-align:right; . One more vertical align text made check here https://jsfiddle.net/o6k5zese/

Comment: Can it be scale text? because i have the scale image beside.  But the fix height with word div that will not be scale following by the image div

Comment: I've applied viewport width  check here https://jsfiddle.net/o6k5zese/4/ . You can reduce that min-height according to your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you wanted the content both vertically and horizontally centered. I've made notes in the CSS.

You can use flexbox:

```css
.word {
  height:300px; /* this is just for the example - it can be any height */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; /* horizontal centering. you can also use flex-start or flex-end */
  background:salmon; /* just to help show that it's working. */
}
```

```html
<div class="word">
 <h1>Hello!!</h1>

</div>
```

Or if the parent element(s) have a defined height, `.words` can be a percentage of that. [Here's a working example in jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/yb59g51y/).

```css
html,
body {
  /* This is just for the example - use whatever parent element. */
  height: 100%;
  /* The height doesn't have to be a percentage. */
}

.word {
  height: 100%;
  /* this is just for the example - it can be any height */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* horizontal centering. you can also use flex-start or flex-end */
  background: salmon;
  /* just to help show that it's working. */
}
```

```html
<div class="word">
  <h1>Hello!!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: i want the .word div scale when i resize the browser( because i have the word description on the right hand side and picture on the left ) Share 50% 50% space . if i scale the broswer, the picture will scale down, but the word will not scale down. How can i fix it

Comment: your question was how to keep the text in the center when `.word` was any size - not scaling text.

Answer (score 1):

Hello I try following code and it perfect fit as you want, I hope this will help you.

```css
  .word {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;float: left;
        height: 90px;
        background: #000;
        color: #FFF;
        line-height: 90px;
     }
    .word  h1{
      font-size:5.9vw;
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      width: auto;
      margin: 0px;
      transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
      -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
      -moz-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
      -o-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
      -ms-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

```html
  <div class="word">
     <h1>Hello!!</h1>
  </div>
```

second method for this also work change the css code as follow

```
 .word {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    height: 90px;
    background: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 90px;
    display: table;
}
.word h1{
  font-size:5.9vw;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `display:flex`,
you can also use `margin:auto` on the child element.

```css
.word {
  height:300px; /* this is just for the example - it can be any height */
  display: flex;
  background:salmon; /* just to help show that it's working. */
}
.word h1{
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="word">
 <h1>Hello!!</h1>

</div>
```